# mongoDB find document greatest date and check value

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a Conversation collection that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "QzuTQYkGDBkgGnHrZ",
    "participants": [
      {
        "id": "YymyFZ27NKtuLyP2C"
      },
      {
        "id": "d3y7uSA2aKCQfLySw",
        "lastVisited": "2016-02-04T02:59:10.056Z",
        "lastMessage": "2016-02-04T02:59:10.056Z"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "e4iRefrkqrhnokH7Y",
    "participants": [
      {
        "id": "d3y7uSA2aKCQfLySw",
        "lastVisited": "2016-02-04T03:26:33.953Z",
        "lastMessage": "2016-02-04T03:26:53.509Z"
      },
      {
        "id": "SRobpwtjBANPe9hXg",
        "lastVisited": "2016-02-04T03:26:35.210Z",
        "lastMessage": "2016-02-04T03:15:05.779Z"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "twXPHb76MMxQ3MQor",
    "participants": [
      {
        "id": "d3y7uSA2aKCQfLySw"
      },
      {
        "id": "SRobpwtjBANPe9hXg",
        "lastMessage": "2016-02-04T03:27:35.281Z",
        "lastVisited": "2016-02-04T03:57:51.036Z"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Each conversation (document) can have a participant object with the properties of `id`, `lastMessage`, `lastVisited`.

Sometimes, depending on how new the conversation is, some of these values don't exist just yet (such as `lastMessage`, `lastVisited`).

What I'm trying to do is compare each participant in each individual conversation (document) and see if out of the all the participants, the greatest `lastMessage` field value belongs to the logged in user. Otherwise, I'm assuming that the conversation has messages that the logged in user hasn't seen yet. I want to get that count of messages that the user possibly hasn't seen yet.

In the example above, say we're logged in as `d3y7uSA2aKCQfLySw`. We can see that he was the last person to send a message for conversation `1`, `2` BUT not `3`. The count returning for how many updated conversations that `d3y7uSA2aKCQfLySw` hasn't seen should be 1.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I haven't the slightest clue as to how to approach the issue. My apologies for the lengthy question.

Answer (score 1):

It is always advisable to store dates as `ISODate` rather than strings to leverage the flexibility provided by various [`date operators`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) in the `aggregation` framework.

One way of getting the count is to,

- `$match` the conversations in which the user is involved.
- `$unwind` the `participants` field.
- `$sort` by the `lastMessage` field in descending order
- `$group` by the `_id` to get back the original conversations intact, and get the latest message per group(conversation) using the `$first` operator.
- `$project` a field with value `0`, for each group where the top most record is of the user we are looking for and `1` for others.
- `$group` again to get the total count of the conversations in which he has not been the last one to send a message.

sample code:

```
var userId = "d3y7uSA2aKCQfLySw"; 
db.t.aggregate([
 {
    $match:{"participants.id":userId}
 },
 {
    $unwind:"$participants"
 },
 {
    $sort:{"participants.lastMessage":-1}
 },
 {
    $group:{"_id":"$_id","lastParticipant":{$first:"$$ROOT.participants"}}
 },
 {
    $project:{
   "hasNotSeen":{$cond:[
                         {$eq:["$lastParticipant.id",userId]},
                         0,
                         1
                       ]},
   "_id":0}
 },
 {
    $group:{"_id":null,"count":{$sum:"$hasNotSeen"}}
 },
 {
    $project:{"_id":0,"numberOfConversationsNotSeen":"$count"}
 }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it does what I'm looking for. Question though, can something like this be done without aggregate? I'm using MeteorJS and a big priority for me is that everything is working in real time (reactive). Unfortunately [this](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/aggregate) package that provides me the ability to use aggregation limits the reactivity.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to try this function.

```
function findUseen(uId) {
    var numMessages = db.demo.aggregate(
        [
            {
                $project: {
                    "participants.lastMessage": 1,
                    "participants.id": 1
                }
            },
            {$unwind: "$participants"},
            {$sort: {"participants.lastMessage": -1}},
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$_id",
                    participantsId: {$first: "$participants.id"},
                    lastMessage: {$max: "$participants.lastMessage"}
                }
            },
            {$match: {participantsId: {$ne: uId}}},
        ]
    ).toArray().length;

    return numMessages;
}
```

calling `findUnseen("d3y7uSA2aKCQfLySw")` will return 1.

I have adopted this function just to return count, but as you see it's easy to tweak it to return all unseen message metadata too.